# Looking for Italicized Text In Python using re.sub

Tags: python, python-re

the gist of this is, i'm making a function that removes italicized text by using re.sub and duplicate the text. The function has an argument named sentence that contains a string.

A few examples:

```
sentence = <i>All of this text is italicized.</i>
Return value = "All of this text is italicized. All of this text is italicized."

sentence = <i>beep</i><i>bop</i><i>boop</i><i>bonk</i>
Return value: "beep beepbop bopboop boopbonk bonk"

sentence = "I <i>Like</i>, food because <i>it's so great</i>!"
return value: "I Like Like food because it's so great it's so great!".
```

Here's what i have so far:

```
pattern = r'<.*?>'
return re.sub(pattern, i, sentence)
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your pattern is wrong - it matches everything from first `<` to last `>` which is clearly not what you want. Second, `for i in sentence` makes no sense - iterating over a string gives you single characters of the string, which won't match your pattern anyway.

This, however, seems to do what you want:

```
return re.sub('<i>(.*?)</i>', r'\1 \1', sentence)
```

`\1` is a reference to whatever the first capturing group, ie. `(.*?)`, has matched, and it is used twice to achieve the doubling effect.